# Do something if multiple (AND operator) functions have been executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm tryng to do some jQuery stuff when both `instagramLoadError` and `imagesLoaded` functions have been loaded.

For this I'm using `if(instagramLoadError() && imagesLoaded()){})` but it's not working as expected.

I'm just starting with JS but I read something about "scope" saying that I can't target my `instagramLoadError` and `imagesLoaded` functions since it's not within the same scope. For this reason or another I'm still getting the "x function is not defined" error.

What should I do in this case?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
(function(){
new InstagramFeed({
'on_error': function instagramLoadError(){
return true;
}
});
})();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#myDiv').imagesLoaded(function(){
return true;
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
if(instagramLoadError() && imagesLoaded()){
// do some stuff if both instagramLoadError and imagesLoaded functions have been executed
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var isInstagramLoadError = false;
   var isImagesLoaded = false;

  (function() {
    new InstagramFeed({
      'on_error': function() {
        isInstagramLoadError = true;
        checkBoth();
      }
    });
  })();
  
  $('#myDiv').imagesLoaded(function() {
    isImagesLoaded = true;
    checkBoth();
  });
  
  function checkBoth() {
    if (isInstagramLoadError && isImagesLoaded) {
      // do some stuff if both instagramLoadError and imagesLoaded functions have been executed
    };
  };
});
```

The issue is that you are dealing with asynchronous callback functions. Each function will run when something happens (Instagram load error or images loaded) and the order of the two cannot be guaranteed. So to deal with this, have each function update a variable and then call a common function `checkBoth()` to check the variables.

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly! But is this solution a kind of "workaround"? Or is there a "best practice" or "official" solution?

Comment: Recently, [promises](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_promise.asp) and [async](https://www.w3schools.com/JS//js_async.asp) functions were introduced to make it easier to deal with asynchronous functions. They're only supported by newer browsers, however. I'm not sure there's one standard recommended practice for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Promise.all method. which will wait for all promise to complete

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function Instagram(){
new InstagramFeed({
'on_error': function instagramLoadError(){
return true;
}
function  images(){
$('#myDiv').imagesLoaded(function(){
return true;
}
Promise.all([Instagram(),images()]).then(res=>{
    if(res[0] && res[1]){
 // do some code
}
})
})
```

Promise. all will wait for functions to complete and store the data returning in an array.